# What are customvalue objects in the Ansible vmware_guest module?

Tags: ansible, vmware, vsphere, vcenter

We use Ansible extensively in a VMware environment. I found the customvalues option in the Ansible documentation at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vmware_guest_module.html#options.

What are custom values in this module?

Does this use VMware tagging or is it something else?

Answer (score 4):

Long time without an answer. In sake for completeness:
customvalues obejcts in Ansible's vmware_guest module refers to the options under VM settings -> VM Options -> Configuration parameters in vSphere [As described in VMware KB](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.html.hostclient.doc/GUID-8C639077-FF16-4D5D-9A7A-E16902CE00C2.html)

format is:

```
vmware_guest:
  customvalues:
    - key: "option_name"
      value: "option_value"
    - key: "another_option_name_if_needed"
      value: "the_other_options_value"
```